# Framework for GAE without commiting to Vendor Lockin

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, frameworks

I am looking for a Framework (Java is preferred), that will run on Goggle App Engine, but is also possible to switch over to another cloud vendor like maybe AWS-Beanstalk or OpenStack. For sure you will have to change some properties files and stuff but I don't want to change much of my code.

And also I'm quite concerned about the Performance, the App should with decent performance even on the Free GAE offer. With growing size I maybe commit to payment, however as a starting point payment isn't planned.

So my first thought was the Spring Framework, but I have no experience with it and so I am not sure if it fits my needs? Are there any serious competitors even for business applications?

As a final point if have to state that I am quite experienced with developing Java but haven't done anything with a java framework (in aspect to an application framework) yet. The only Framework I've used till now was Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the compatibility of different Java frameworks in: [Will it play in GAE?](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava)

Spring is composed by different modules. Some of them will run out-of-the-box, some of them require some patches. It really depends on the classes you can run in GAE, defined in the [Google class whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist).

IMHO, I find it anoying each time I have to fix a library in order to make it work on GAE, so when it is possible I use full Java spec support PaaS, like [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What are your experiences? How often do you have to touch a module? Are roughly all modules from Spring compatible? I actually don't want to modify any FrameWork Classes. However the 'Will it play in GAE?' Site tells, that Spring MVC and Spring ORM are compatible and the Spring Security is Semi Compatible. What is your experience with Heroku, here especially the free offering as well. Will it be enough to have a SpringApp that will handle maybe 4 or 5 People using the App at the same time?

Comment: Well, recently I faced two main limitations, you cannot use POI (Apache lib to manage excel files) and you can't do anything with java graphics (java.awt classes are blacklisted). However, if you use extensively google APIs it is much simple to access them from GAE. Heroku free offer would perform great for only 5 users, Spring runs out-of-the-box and they also offer a free 5MB postresql instance

Comment: Hi, again thank your very much! This really helped me a lot. So I think probably I want to use Apache POI or something similar. So this fact and the fact that there will be a lot of other libs you can't use, I will forget about GAE. So I will have a much deeper look at Heroku now. But from a first Point of View it seems that it fits my needs pretty good. However I am not sure if the Database will fit my needs. Maybe I will use an external Database. Do you know by chance how an external DB performs in Heroku? Best Regards

Comment: I don't have any experience connecting DBs outside Heroku, but they offer really cheap upgrades to the free one, 10 Million rows for 9$/month, cheers!